# Printing PDF files in WPF with customized PrintTicket

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, printing, reporting-services

In a current project I need to print reports I received from SSRS in Pdf format. So far I have learned that Pdf and WPF are not friends at all. But there is even more to the requirements:

- Pdfs should be printed to a printer without displaying a print
  dialog.
- Some reports require paper from a particular InputBin (so this must
  be configurable)

I have seen quite a lot approaches to this. Also I investigated some WPF – PDF Libraries, but none of them cover these requirements.

The solution I have is to get the report as Imagesource from SSRS, then creating an `Image` WPF Control for each source. Afterwards creating a `FixedDocument` with each page containing the `Image` Control created.

This works, however, the files created are quite large and it takes too long to print them. Therefore printing a native PDF file approach would be better.

What I want is this:

```
var bytes = GetSomeReportFromReportingServices();
var pdfDocuments = new PdfDocument(bytes);

var printQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
var printTicket = printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket();

//Extension method to set the input bin
printTicket.SetInputBin("SomeInputBinDifferentFromDefault");

//Set some other PrintTicket Properties
//[...]

pdfDocument.Print(printQueue, printTicket);
```

Easy as that. All I want is to configure a PrintTicket and printing that pdf to a printer. Is there some Library/ component out there capable of doing something like that?

Comment: Have you tried PDFView4Net from O2 Solutions? They support printing of PDF documents. http://www.o2sol.com/pdfview4net/overview.htm